# The field HttpStatus.DESTINATION_LOCKED is deprecated

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat

I am working with java and Eclipse announce me that

```
The field HttpStatus.DESTINATION_LOCKED is deprecated
```

Which status replace for HttpStatus.DESTINATION_LOCKED ?

Comment: Well the javadoc point you to the RFC that tells you which to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadocs for the deprecation on [`HttpStatus`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html#DESTINATION_LOCKED) exactly tell you where to look for that answer. It points you to the updated [WebDAV draft](https://tools.ietf.org/rfcdiff?difftype=--hwdiff&url2=draft-ietf-webdav-protocol-06.txt).

Here you can find that instead of 421 (`RESOURCE_LOCKED`) you should use 423 (`LOCKED`).